# In 2d CFT, why the $T_{zz}$ component of energy-momentum tensor is holomorphic even at quantum level?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In 2d Conformal Field Theory, the $T_{zz}$ component of energy-momentum tensor is treated as a holomorphic function $T(z)=T_{zz}$ at quantum level such as in OPE involved energy-momentum tensor.

I know, in classical theory, this conclusion comes from the traceless and conservation equation of $T_{\mu\nu}$. 
The traceless leads to $T_{z\bar{z}}=0$ and then conservation law implies
 $$\partial_{\bar z} T_{zz}=\partial_z T_{\bar z\bar z}=0$$
However, a quantum field does not need to satisfy the classical equation of motion. (Since in path integral fomalism $\int D\phi\  e^{-S[\phi ]}$, the quantum field $\phi$ can be any smooth field configuration and the energy-momentum tensor is a functional of field $\phi$.) The conservation equation is  classical。

Then, why should the $T_{zz}$ still be a holomorphic function at quantum level?

Comment: Stress-tensor is both conserved and traceless as a quantum operator. Inside path integral this is valid up to contact terms, as all equation of motion are. (Traceless part assumes that at quantum level you still have conformal invariance, i.e. the beta function vanishes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will follow Di Francesco's CFT book. By combining the Ward identities associated to conformal invariance (Eq. 5.32), you can get to

$$ \partial_{\bar{z}} \Big[ \langle T(z, \bar{z} ) X \rangle - \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{z-w_i} \partial_{w_i} \langle X \rangle + \frac{h_i}{(z-w_i)^2} \langle X \rangle \right) \Big] = 0  , \qquad \qquad  \text{(Eq. 5.39)}$$

where $T(z, \bar{z})$ is the "holomorphic" component of the energy-momentum tensor ( in this convention $T(z, \bar{z}) = - 2 \pi T_{zz}$ ) and $X$ is some string of quasi-primary fields $\Phi_1(w_1, \bar{w}_1) ... \Phi_n(w_n, \bar{w}_n)$ with holomorphic dimensions $h_1, ... , h_n$. This means that the correlation function $\langle T(z, \bar{z} ) X \rangle$ is actually **holomorphic** up to the sum

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{z-w_i} \partial_{w_i} \langle X \rangle + \frac{h_i}{(z-w_i)^2} \langle X \rangle \right). $$

Note that this sum is not exactly holomorphic because of the property

$$\partial_{\bar{z}} \frac{1}{z} = \pi \delta (\mathbf{x}), $$

where $\delta (\mathbf{x})$ is the Dirac delta at the point $z$ but in Euclidean coordinates (its normalization may change when changing the coordinates). Therefore, if you apply this property to Eq. 5.39 you can easily see that $\partial_{\bar{z}}  \langle T(z, \bar{z} ) X \rangle$ actually vanishes as long as we don't take $z$ to coincide with some $w_i$ (these are called contact terms and are basically always present in the quantum theory). This is I think what is meant by "$T_{zz}$ is holomorphic at the quantum level".

Comment: +1 – this is also evident in $T_{z \bar{z}} = 0$, which is also only true up to contact terms.

Comment: So it is the correlation function $\langle ...\rangle$ be holomorphic (up to contact terms) rather than the field $T_{zz}$? Then why we always expand the field $T_{zz}$ as $T_{zz}=\sum \frac{L_n}{z^{n+2}}$ without any $\bar z$ terms?

Comment: @JiahaoMao the operator is nothing more than its action on correlation functions, so T is holomorphic by definition

Comment: Yes, the operators always appear inside correlation functions at the end of the day. I wouldn't say $T$ is holomorphic by definition though. It's a result from Lorentz and scale invariance

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I am still confused. In path integral formalism, the equation of motion(e.o.m) of a field $\phi(x)$ satisfies the Dyson-Schwinger equation which says the correlation function of e.o.m with other inserted operators vanishes up to contact terms. But we do not define quantum field $\phi(x)$ in path integral to be a solution of e.o.m. The quantum field $\phi(x)$ can be any smooth function of $x$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean now. Yes, the correlation function of an e.o.m. is zero up to contact terms, and this is actually what we have. From the e.o.m. $\partial_{\bar{z}} T_{zz}=0$ we get $\partial_{\bar{z}} \langle T_{zz} X \rangle = $ contact terms.

Comment: @JiahaoMao your confusion comes from identifying two different objects both occasionally called “quantum field”. There’s the fluctuating field that appears in the path integral. And there’s also the operator-valued distribution that is called “quantum field”. I’d argue that the term fits the latter more. That’s what is always meant by “quantum field” in CFT jargon. So the claim that T is holomorphic is equivalent to the claim that the correlation function of T with any other vertex operators is holomorphic modulo contact terms.

Comment: In the operator formalism, all operators satisfy their equation of motion.  This is just like in QM where the $\hat q(t)$ heisenber operator in the harmonic oscillator obeys $d^2 \hat q/dt^2+\omega^2 \hat q=0$.

Comment: Thank you all! Maybe I understand it now. It is the operator-valued quantum field $T_{zz}$ that is holomorphic. And the Laurent expansion $T_{zz}=\sum \frac{L_m}{z^{m+2}}$ is for operator-valued quantum field $T_{zz}$ rather than fluctuation quantum field in path integral.